# Reading hdf5 file using h5py slows down over time

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py, hdf

I have an hdf5 file of shape 80000 * 401408. I need to read data from it in batches of size 64 but the indices can be random say (5, 0, 121, .., 2).

The problem is that while initially the reads are quite consistent and a batch takes say 0.5 seconds to complete, after a while some of the batches take longer upto 10 seconds while some batches are still being read fast. I have observed as more and more reads take place, the reading process is slowing down.

```
hf = h5py.File( conv_file,'r')
conv_features = hf['conv_features']
while True:
    conv_batch = [None for i in range(64)]
    for i in range(0, 64):
        conv_batch[count] = np.reshape(conv_features[some_random_index], [14, 14, 2048] )
    # time for each of the above reads for conv_bacth is different.. varies from 0.5 to 5 seconds.. and slows down over time.
```

I am not using chunks

Comment: Sure you're not running out of memory and start working on your swapping device or something like that?

Comment: No, I am not running out of memory. The process is just getting slower over time. I am reusing the same variables and only reading the reference to the hdf5 file once.

Comment: Not quite sure if one can determine the problem from the example you're showing there. I'm also not sure why you're using the `deep-learning` tag here. Maybe post your actual code and not just this small excerpt.

Comment: displayname is right, it is hard to diagnose this problem if we don't have enough information to reproduce it.

Comment: I wanted to know if it is usual for hdf5 to have variable time reads (because of the random indices access) The time to read 64 vectors spans from 0.5 to 5 seconds and as I mentioned, it slows down over time. Apart from the above, there is very little that has anything to do with hdf5.

Comment: The HDF5 library caches metadata and data about open HDF5 files. Have you tried closing/opening the file for every access? It is worth timing this approach.

Comment: `h5py` 'fancy-indexing' warns that indexing performance may be poor.  http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#fancy-indexing.  Remember that a disk file is inherently a serial device, so reading from two widely separated 'rows' requires large file `seek` moves.

Comment: Is the file compressed?

Comment: @kakk11 No the file is not compressed.

Comment: @hpaulj I see. The data is on an SSD so thought that should not be a big issue. I am more concerned with why the random access is way faster in some cases than others.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Thanks for the suggestion! I will try this and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I tried it with a smaller dataset (3000,401408) and could not reproduce your problem (Win64, Python 2.7, newest available h5py-version available in Anaconda). The read speed at the beginning is aproximately the sequential read speed of my SSD and becomes faster because some data is chached in RAM. Could you provide more information (Python version, h5py version, operating system)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried controlling chunk size with your dataset. Set the chunk size to a reasonable and commonly accessed portion.

e.g if you commonly accessed your 80000 * 401408 data per row,
the chunks would be efficiently read if the chunks were (1, 401408) or perhaps 
(1, 200704).

Depending on your access pattern, the chunk size can affect hugely on time taken to access. You can also consider using compression.